# Image Slider Div Error

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I am creating a image slider with Ajax, but having issues adding a div to my HTML part so I can center the slider... Below I added the centerSliderDiv to center it, but doesn't work. I tried adding a simple background color to test, but that doesn't work either. Not sure why the centerSlideDiv is not working! Any thoughts?

Thanks

```
<div id = "centerSlideDiv">
                <button class="prev">
                    Previous
                </button>
                <div id="images">
                    <div>
                        <img src='firstImage.jpg'/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src='secondImage.jpg'/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src='thirdImage.jpg'/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="next">
                    Next
                </button>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
button {
    float: left;   
}
#images div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left; 
    height:209px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;

}​

#centerSlideDiv{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this :

```
#images div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left; 
    height:209px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;

}​
```

to this :

```
#images div {
    border: 1px solid #000;

    height:209px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;

}​
```

Click this demo : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/d88ry/)
I update demo for you click this link : [DEMOUPDATE](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/dEqLm)

Comment: this takes each photo and makes them stack on each other vertically. I want the to go left to right horizontally but centered.

Comment: @user3356901 i update demo page for you click my unswer DEMOUPDATE link

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow:hidden; to your #centerSlideDiv and it should work.

```
#centerSlideDiv{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:green;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I added the overflow, but still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: This is your code, with overflow:hidden added. http://jsfiddle.net/G5Spv/

It works there.

Comment: thanks for you help... I am not sure why this doesn't work on my computer!

Comment: I think you have some kind of weird character on the css you pasted, try replacing the code you have on your code editor with the one I provided on the jsfiddle. I am not sure about this but worth a try.